# Get last child height of SVG element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor

I'm trying to get the height of the last child for testing purposes.

I can select the element with `$('.nv-series-1 rect:last-child')` but not sure how to get the height specifically.

I tried `$('.nv-series-1 rect:last-child').getBBox()` with no luck.

```
<g class=nv-series-1>
    <rect class="nv-bar positive" x="0" y="206.8" height="13.15" width="86.4"></rect>
    <rect class="nv-bar positive" x="0" y="206.8" height="13.15" width="86.4"></rect>
</g>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the element `by.css` and use [`getAttribute()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) to get the `height` attribute value:

```
var rect = element(by.css('.nv-series-1 rect:last-child'));
expect(rect.getAttribute('height')).toBe('13.15');
```